# How do I get my Testnet listed on chainid.network

Tags: private-blockchain

I need assistance with getting my testnet listed on the website chainid.networks. I have already seen the GitHub examples but I would like to know what each field represents. Thank you!

Comment: I'd ask this questions directly on the Github repo of chainid.network. I think you'd have a better chance to get a better explanation from the authors and contributors there: https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains/issues

Comment: I already got it listed. I figured that would be the best approach and it was. Thank you for the response